# How to write Linq query that pulls top three rows from child table

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I would like to recreate the functionality of an existing stored procedure as a LINQ expression. The procedure uses a "STUFF" function to return the top three fields from a child table into one field of the sproc. I'll add a snippet of the procedure for as a reference:

```
SELECT h.ReqHeaderID,   

STUFF((SELECT TOP(3) ', ' +  l.Nomenclature     FROM    ReqLineItems  l
                                                WHERE l.ReqID  = h.ReqID 
   FOR XML PATH ('')    ),1,1, '')

As OrderedItems

FROM    ReqHeader           h
```

Is there a way to write this in LINQ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can use a [group join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397905.aspx), which is the `join into` clause in query syntax:

```
(from reqHeader in db.ReqHeaders
 join reqLineItem in db.ReqLineItems 
     on reqHeader.ReqID equals reqLineItem.ReqId into reqLineItems
 select new 
        {  
            reqHeader.ReqHeaderId,
            Nomenclatures = reqLineItems.Select(x => x.Nomenclature).Take(3)
        })
.AsEnumerable()
.Select(x => new
             {
                 x.ReqHeaderId,
                 Nomenclatures = String.Join(", ", x.Nomenclatures.ToArray())
             })
```

I joined the strings after calling `AsEnumerable()` because I believe you can only join the strings together in LINQ to Objects and not in Linq to Entities.

Comment: I don't see where this would get the nomenclature of the first three line items into a string. Also, I would want the nomenclatures to be comma dileminated. Any ideas?

Comment: @AlanFisher: I was going by just your description because that code went way over my head :(.  I updated my answer.

Comment: Since I am using Linq to Entities, I am going to assume your answer is correct and re=post my question to be more specific to what I am doing. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @AlanFisher: This answer does the joining in LINQ to Objects, so if it is not working, it is incorrect.